# Extending the ompl_ros_interface

Tags: ros, ompl, ompl-ros-interface, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While looking through the [OMPL documentation](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/api_overview.html) I found a bunch of interesting features, such as planning in control space and creating [custom (problem-specific) state samplers](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/availableSamplers.html).

Are these features (Is access to these features) already implemented in the [ompl_ros_interface](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface) and I just didn't find them?

If not, are there plans to integrate them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38630/extending-the-ompl_ros_interface/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-07-12**:
FYI, I argue that the above question is a superset of http://answers.ros.org/question/38338/how-to-do-ompl-planners-benchmarking-inside-ros/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point only functionality from the geometric:: namespace from OMPL is exposed in ompl_ros_interface. This will continue to be the case for a while.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0